# UIImage error with dynamic string

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios4, iphone-sdk-3.0

I'm trying to load an image into the cell, 
The following code is working correctly :

```
NSString *imageURL = @"http://localhost/images/image2.jpg";
NSData *imageData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:imageURL]];
UIImage *rowImage = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:imageData];

cell.image=rowImage;
```

but when i change imageURL to be dynamic , the image isn't displayed :

```
NSString *imageURL = [[stories objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"image"];
```

You might be saying the problem is in :

```
[[stories objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"image"];
```

But it's not , i've tried to log it and the output is as expected :

```
NSSLog(@"%@",[[stories objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"image"]);
//Outputs http://localhost/images/image2.jpg
```

What could be wrong  ?

Comment: It looks OK. Where are you are getting the `stories` array from?

Comment: It comes from XMLParser delegate method , but it already outputs the value .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am guessing there is space before or after the string. So do this,

```
NSString *imageURL = [[stories objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"image"];
imageURL = [imageURL stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];

NSData *imageData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:imageURL]];
UIImage *rowImage = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:imageData];
```

While this should mostly fix your issue, I suggest you trim the strings before adding to the dictionary during the XML parsing.

You should also ensure you release both `imageData` and `rowImage`. You might be doing it already but its not in the code above so I just wanted to indicate that it could be leaking.

Answer (score 1):

try this one

```
    NSString *imageURL =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[stories objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"image"]];
```